# Autopopulate the fields based on a look field value from a standard object

Tags: trigger

Can anyone help me out with this,
[image]

This is from a custom object " Quotation", The look up field " Main Driver" is a look up to Personal account object. The below fields are as well exists in the personal account. I need whatever value would be choosen in the main driver, automatically the below values will get pop up on below fields. I need to write a trigger for this ( I cant use formula field, as its depends upon another criteria field, so somtimes the user need to enter values manually in these fields , Process builder also doesnt worked).
I tried to write a trigger, but its not working , showing issue as " Error: Compile Error: IN operator must be used with an iterable expression at line 12 column 104 " Can anyone plz rectify my trigger to make it work. Thnx .( I just have taken two fields below for test)

```
trigger MainDriverRelatedFields on Quotation__c (before insert,before update) {

Quotation__c newQuote=new Quotation__c();

for(Quotation__c obj : Trigger.new){
newQuote=obj ;
    }
    List<Account> Acc= [SELECT id,Age__c, Acccidents_in_the_last_12_mnths__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: newQuote.Main_Driver__r];

     if(newQuote.Main_Driver__c!=null) {
       newQuote.AgeMainD__c=Acc.Age__c;

       newQuote.Accidents_in_the_last_12_mnthsMainD__c= Acc.Acccidents_in_the_last_12_mnths__c;

        }
}
```

Comment: How is this question different to your previous question?  Please make sure your previous question is either marked as answered, and if this is a completely different question, then we can leave this one open.

Comment: Dear Both, Its different in the sense of the trigger code I have written and the Error messages that it showed is different. I changed the code here, and it showed me a different kind of error.